# Определение планов в сцене ARCore Android

Tags: android, arcore

Изучаю примеры ARCore от Google и у меня возникла проблема с определением планов.

Когда я использую, например, приложение [Google Measure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.tango.measure), то я вижу, что планы будут получены после появления массы отметок на объектах - скриншот [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сразу после этого появятся планы, в которых точки расположены очень близко.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё работает быстро и замечательно.

=============================

Когда я создаю похожий фрагмент, у меня нет отметок на объектах, а точки на планах расположены с большой дистанцией.

Работает всё немного медленнее, чем у Гугла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код взят из образцов гитхаба и очень прост:

```
arFragment = (ARFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.vr_fragment);
```

- этого достаточно, чтобы планы начали определяться.

Вопрос: как мне добиться того, чтобы у меня были отметки на объектах, по которым ARCore построит планы, на которых точки будут расположены очень близко?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выяснилось, что определение планов работает одинаково, а отображение точек или планов можно настроить следующим образом:

1. Поместите в `src/main/assets/textures` файл с текстурой, которая должна отображаться при поиске планов. Я нарисовал небольшую белую точку:
   [image: небольшая белая точка]
2. Вызовите метод для изменения текстуры, указав необходимые параметры масштабирования. В моём случае это

   `material.setFloat2(MATERIAL_UV_SCALE,50f, 50f);`
3. Сам метод:

`String texturePath = "textures/little_dot.png";`

`Texture.Sampler sampler = Texture.Sampler.builder()
    .setMinFilter(Texture.Sampler.MinFilter.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)
    .setMagFilter(Texture.Sampler.MagFilter.LINEAR)
    .setWrapModeR(Texture.Sampler.WrapMode.REPEAT)
    .setWrapModeS(Texture.Sampler.WrapMode.REPEAT)
    .setWrapModeT(Texture.Sampler.WrapMode.REPEAT)
    .build();`

`Texture.builder().setSource(() -> getAssets().open(texturePath))
    .setSampler(sampler)
    .build().thenAccept((texture) -> {
        mArFragment.getArSceneView().getPlaneRenderer().getMaterial()
            .thenAccept((material) -> {
                material.setTexture(MATERIAL_TEXTURE, texture);
                material.setFloat2(MATERIAL_UV_SCALE,50f, 50f);
            });
        }).exceptionally(ex ->{ Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read an asset file", ex);
            return null;} );`

Итог замены текстуры:

[image: Итог замены текстуры]

(что то с форматирование не очень сложилось, но, надеюсь, понятно описал)
Happy coding!